# How many possible way for barcode to appear with limitation constrain

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is one of homeworks from a grader I've got. I've been struggling on this question for two days now. The topic is about Dynamic programming and I have no idea how to make sense of it.

The detail is the following.

A barcode consists of black and white vertical lines in different arrangement. For simplicity, we use a string of “0” and “1” to identify a barcode such that “0” represents a black line while “1” represents a white line.

A barcode is designed to be robust to error thus it has to follow some specific rules:

1) A barcode must consists of exactly **N** lines

2) There can be no more than **M** consecutive lines of same color. For example, when **M=3**, the barcode “01100001” is illegal because it consists of four consecutive white lines. However, 1001100 is legal.

3) We define “color changing” as follows. Color changing occurs when two
consecutive lines have different colors. For example, 1001100 has 3 color
changing. A barcode must have exactly **K** color changing.

4) The first line is always a black line.

We interest in knowing the number of possible barcode with respect to given
values of **N**, **M** and **K**.

**Input**
There are only one line contains 3 integers N, M and K where 1 <= N,M <= 30 and 0 <= K <= 30

**Output**
The output must contain exactly one line giving the number of possible barcodes.

**For example**

**Input**

```
4 3 1
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Input**

```
5 2 2
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Input**

```
7 9 4
```

**Output**

```
15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each step ( the i barcode ) we have 2 options: either choose it white or black, then depend on that update your state (m and k).

here a pseudo Java code with comments, don't hesitate to ask if something is not clear:

```
    static int n,m,k,memo[][][][];
    static int dp(int i,int mm,int kk,int last) {
        if(mm > m || kk > k) return 0; // limitation constrains
        if(i==n) return kk==k?1:0; // if we build our barcode ( i == n ), we need to check color changing if it's ok return 1 else return 0
        if(memo[i][mm][kk][last] != -1) return memo[i][mm][kk][last]; // momoization
        int ans = 0;
        ans += dp(i+1,last==1?mm+1:1,kk+(last!=1?1:0),1); // choose black as a color of this one and update state ( mm, kk )
        ans += dp(i+1,last==0?mm+1:1,kk+(last!=0?1:0),0); // choose white as a color of this one and update state ( mm, kk )
        return memo[i][mm][kk][last] = ans;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        n = 4; m = 3; k = 1;
        memo = new int[n+1][m+1][k+1][2];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j=0;j<=m;j++) for(int l=0;l<=k;l++) Arrays.fill(memo[i][j][l], -1);
        System.out.print(dp(1,1,0,1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite simple recurrence relation, if T(N, M, K) is the output :

```
T(N, M, K) = T(N - 1, M, K - 1) + T(N - 2, M, K - 1) + ... + T(N - M, M, K - 1)
```

A valid barcode (N, M, K) is always a smaller valid barcode plus one new colour, the size of this new colour could be anything from 1 to M.

Thanks to this relation you can create for each M, a N x K table and solve the problem in O(N*M*K) with dynamic programming.

These rules should be enough to initialize the recurrence:

```
T(N, M, K) = 0 if (K >= N) and 1 if (K = N - 1)
T(N, M, K) = 0 if ((K+1) * M < N)
```